# Collect text data through ipywidgets and update a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am trying to collect data through ipywidgets. The objective once all the fields are filled , pressing the submit button should populate a row in a data frame.
I wrote the following code

```
class record():
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = widgets.Text(description='id')
        self.paper = widgets.Text(description='paper')
        self.objective = widgets.Text(description='objective')
        self.language = widgets.Text(description='language')
        self.citations = widgets.Text(description='citations')
        self.notes = widgets.Text(description='notes')
        self.button = widgets.Button(description="Submit")
        self.button.on_click(self.on_button_clicked)
        display(self.id, self.paper, self.objective, self.language,self.citations,self.notes,self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self,b):
        data = ('|').join([self.id.value,self.paper.value,self.objective.value,self.language.value,self.citations.value,self.notes.value])
        populate(data)

r =record()
```

The `populate` method has the code to populate the entries to the dataframe. id, paper, objective, language, citations, and notes are the column names of the data frame. Populate methods reads a saved dataframe adds an additional row and saves it. I am new to using ipywidgets how to call the `populate` function on button press?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an empty pandas dataframe at the beginning: `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('id', 'paper', 'objective','language','citations','notes'))`
and populate it each time the record button is being pressed:

```py
def on_button_clicked(self,b):
    data = {'id':self.id.value,'paper':self.paper.value,'objective':self.objective.value,'language':self.language.value,'citations':self.citations.value,'notes':self.notes.value} #create a dictionary with the values from the widgets
    df.loc[len(df)]=data #append a new row at the end of the dataframe
```

And here is  the full code:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('id', 'paper', 'objective','language','citations','notes'))
class record():
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = widgets.Text(description='id')
        self.paper = widgets.Text(description='paper')
        self.objective = widgets.Text(description='objective')
        self.language = widgets.Text(description='language')
        self.citations = widgets.Text(description='citations')
        self.notes = widgets.Text(description='notes')
        self.button = widgets.Button(description="Submit")
        self.button.on_click(self.on_button_clicked)
        display(self.id, self.paper, self.objective, self.language,self.citations,self.notes,self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self,b):
        data = {'id':self.id.value,'paper':self.paper.value,'objective':self.objective.value,'language':self.language.value,'citations':self.citations.value,'notes':self.notes.value}
        df.loc[len(df)]=data
        print(df)
        
r =record()
```

Below is an example of the dataframe being populated over 3 iterations:

`df` after first iteration:

```
  id paper objective language citations notes
0  a     b         c        d         e     f
```

`df` second iteration:

```
  id paper objective language citations notes
0  a     b         c        d         e     f
1  g     h         i        j         k     l
```

and `df` after third time:

```
  id paper objective language citations notes
0  a     b         c        d         e     f
1  g     h         i        j         k     l
2  m     n         o        p         q     r
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use the following code and it will populate the data frame `df` every time `Submit` button is clicked:

```
from ipywidgets import interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('ID', 'paper', 'objective','language','citations','notes'))

def populate(data):
    df.loc[len(df.index)] = data
    print(df)

def call_populate(ID, paper, objective, language, citations, notes):
    data = [ID, paper, objective, language, citations, notes]
    populate(data)
                  
im = interact_manual(call_populate, ID=widgets.Text(), paper=widgets.Text(), objective=widgets.Text(), \
                     language=widgets.Text(), citations=widgets.Text(), notes=widgets.Text())

im.widget.children[6].description = "Submit"
```

The widgets looks like this in Jupyter Notebook:
[image]

I have not used `id` in this code because it's a reserved word for built-in function in Python.

If `Submit` is clicked when `ID = 1, paper = Diamond, objective = History, language = Urdu, citations = 421, notes = None` is entered into the text boxes, `df` becomes:

```
  ID    paper objective language citations notes
0  1  Diamond   History     Urdu       421  None
```

When `Submit` is clicked with `ID = 2, paper = Brain and behavior, objective = Neuroscience, language = English, citations = 101, notes = Biology` is entered, `df` becomes:

```
  ID               paper     objective language citations    notes
0  1             Diamond       History     Urdu       421     None
1  2  Brain and behavior  Neuroscience  English       101  Biology
```

If you can modify argument of `populate` from `data` to `ID, paper, objective, language, citations, notes`, you can directly use widget to invoke `populate`. In that case, the function declaration of `populate` would like:

```
def populate(ID, paper, objective, language, citations, notes):
   # Transform inputs to data and pass that to df
   ...
```

In this case, your widget will need to call `populate` directly, keeping everything else same in the code written above for widget:

```
im = interact_manual(populate, ...)
```